# Logging into MySQL as a different user (Windows 10, command prompt)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to login to MySQL with a user other than root. I've already created the user and granted it the privileges I need.

In command prompt, i'm typing in the filepath to `mysql.exe`.

> C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysql.exe

Doing so changes the text at the start of the line to mysql>, but `-u` and `-p` don't work from there.

I also tried adding `-u` and `-p` to the above line, but it achieves the same result.

I'm sure i'm missing something extremely simple, but I would appreciate anyone willing to help me out.

UPDATE: Solution found. It actually was very simple, but in case somebody does happen to have the same issue, I needed to make the following change:

> C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysql.exe -u myusername -p

Comment: If you enter `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysql.exe -u notroot -p` you should get prompted for a password. Put a duff password in. Are you refused access?

Comment: That worked to get it to prompt me for a password, and yes, it refused me access.